# I never made you blinded, or am I not?

Tags: riddle, wordplay

> Rather than usual I'll have grey area,
>       other times I don't.
>
> You could say I'm being feared by,
>       gladly only to a few.
>
> Being part of me, are you?
>       I don't really care.
>
> Vision or imaginary?
>       Only your mind knows.

**Who / what am I?**

Comment: Alex - one of these answers correct or are you looking for something different?

Comment: There's a correct answer!  However there's a line haven't solve yet if you're interested in looking for it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you

> Visible light? It might be something related like color, rainbow, etc.

I'm guessing because

> The initial letters are ROYGBIVO, standing for Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue, Indigo, and Violet. Not sure about the last O. Maybe you just needed an extra line.

The title: I never made you blinded, or am I not?

> Very intense light can blind you, but in general light doesn't blind you.

Rather than usual I'll have grey area,
other times I don't.

> Not entirely sure. Light can be gray or not.

You could say I'm being feared by,
gladly only to a few.

> Not that many people are afraid of light. But there's [Photophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photophobia)

Being part of me, are you?
I don't really care.

Vision or imaginary?
Only your mind knows.

> Which wavelengths correspond to visible light is more of a coincidence of biology than anything. The visible colors are the ones that our mind distinguishes.

Comment: ROYGBIVO seems is ROYGBIV + O for "oneness". [See results here?](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&biw=1367&bih=803&ei=P6e1WvKuFMXkjwOes5-ACA&q=roygbivo+model+&oq=roygbivo+model+&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i160k1.4286.5082.0.5144.7.6.0.0.0.0.142.552.1j4.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.5.552...0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i13i5i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.ltSBe21iw_A)

Comment: @Riker That's interesting, but I don't see how that fits into the riddle at all

Comment: O is clearly for octarine, the colour of magic

Comment: This is the correct answer!  I'll accept but there's one more line you haven't solve yet, if you're still interested

Comment: Do you mean the third line? I considered that to be combined with the fourth line in my answer. Or do you mean a different line that I haven't addressed adequately?

Answer (score 6):

I was thinking of:

> The code block that contains the riddle, as opposed to the normal quotation block.

Title: I never made you blinded, or am I not?

> If (as indicated below) people object to the "misuse" of the code block for something that's not code, you could argue it's ultimately not that important anyway.

Rather than usual I'll have grey area, / other times I don't.

> The code block has a grey background, whereas the quotation block has a yellow background.

You could say I'm being feared by, / gladly only to a few.

> I've seen comments (on other Stack Exchange sites) that code blocks should be reserved explicitly for computer code only, or possibly situations where monospaced font is important - and otherwise use quotation blocks to set off a block of text.

Being part of me, are you? / I don't really care.

> With the other interpretation of code blocks, it would be fed into a compiler or interpreter which doesn't have human "opinions" about the code, only a mechanical decision whether it's valid syntactically - so it "doesn't really care".

Vision or imaginary? / Only your mind knows.

> Not sure about this one, perhaps a continuation of the last explanation.

Comment: Not the answer but good attempt!

Answer (score 4):

Going off of Daniel's answer is it

> When an answer is put into ">!"

I never made you blinded, or am I not?

> Just because this hides your answer doe snot mean you cannot look at it.

Rather than usual I'll have grey area,
other times I don't.

> Grey area can mean uncertain and sometimes people put answer into these that are a stretch or quite wrong. Other people put a spot on, correct answer

You could say I'm being feared by,
gladly only to a few.

> Some people are "afraid" to see the correct answer so people put theirs in a ">!". Others will go ahead and hover over it.

Being part of me, are you?
I don't really care.

> I am putting my answer in a ">!" so I guess I am part of it.

Vision or imaginary?
Only your mind knows.

> It may appear to be blocked out but you just have to hover over it to find out.

Comment: Not the answer - if I changed the line from "grey area" to "yellow" it will be a good fit

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is.... --- but now I look at it I'm not the first with this answer.... rats

> You are a rainbow - nice acrostic R, O, Y, G, B, I, V, O for Red, Orange, Yellow Green Blue Indigo Violet and Ochre? -  not sure about the last letter ---- edit and @Riley got there first - well done Riley - too late me...

Rather than usual I'll have grey area,
other times I don't.

> intense rainbows have grey areas

You could say I'm being feared by,
gladly only to a few.

> ?some people like rainbows some don't ?

Being part of me, are you?
I don't really care.

> ? we are all a bit 'on the spectrum' - sorry very tenuous, not sure about this

Vision or imaginary?
Only your mind knows.

> rainbows come up in legend / myth a fair bit...

Answer (score 4):

You are:

> Deja vu

Rather than usual I'll have grey area,
other times I don't.

> Typically you know you're having a false memory (not a grey area), but other times you may strongly be attempting to recall why it's familiar or if it is real (grey area).

You could say I'm being feared by,
gladly only to a few.

> Usually deja vu is benign, but sometimes it's an inauspicious or feared remembrance of something bad (e.g. uh oh, this doesn't feel right).

Being part of me, are you?
I don't really care.

> Deja vu, in a sense, is a joining of two times. You don't care because you're a false memory and it's all in my head anyway.

Vision or imaginary?
Only your mind knows.

> The perplexing nature of deja vu leaves it to our mind to determine if this memory is true or false.

Title:
I never made you blinded, or am I not?

> Did the deja vu mislead me or does the memory "not" exist?

Comment: Not the answer - A little stretchy but I like your way of thinking

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you are

> A shadow.

Here's my reasoning:

Rather than usual I'll have grey area,
other times I don't.

> This might refer to the grey area which surrounds shadows also known as penumbra.

You could say I'm being feared by,
gladly only to a few.

> A reference to one of the most common phobias, the fear of the dark.

Being part of me, are you?
I don't really care.

> If you think about it, we all cast a shadow.

Vision or imaginary?
Only your mind knows.

> We all thought we saw something hiding in the shadows...

Comment: This is the closest to making my question having 2 answers.  Nicely done!

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> justice/law?

**Explanation:**

**Title:** *I never made you blinded, or am I not?*

> Justice is blind, but it cannot make you blind (there are examples in the past where it has, though)

*Rather than usual I'll have grey area,
other times I don't.*

> Law is usually perceived to have grey areas, as in, loopholes, edge cases and such.

*You could say I'm being feared by, 
gladly only to a few.*

> Criminals fear the law, thankfully they make up only a small portion of the population.

*Being part of me, are you?
I don't really care.*

> Without humans, there would be no concept of justice/law. Also, the law doesn't care if you accept it or not, you will be held to it.

*Vision or imaginary? 
Only your mind knows.*

> Is justice/law a perfect, unachievable idea, an imaginary vision, so to say? Without the mind, there would be no concept of justice/law.

Comment: Not the answer - a little stretchy on some lines but good attempt!